# view within view with pagination in codeigniter

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter, pagination

I have a view named "home.php" with a load button. When I click the button I am loading another view having pagination using ajax.

```
print $this->load->view('/layout/superadmin/email_listing', $this->_data, true);
```

For pagination in `email_listing` view, I have below code in model:

```
$config['base_url'] = site_url().'/home';
    $config['total_rows'] = $this->_DB_FORUM->get('orderheader')->num_rows();
    $config['per_page'] = 20;
    $config['use_page_numbers'] = TRUE;
    $config['num_links'] = 20;
    $config['uri_segment'] = 4;
    $config['full_tag_open']='<div class="pagination"><div class="links">';
    $config['full_tag_close']='</div></div>';
    $this->pagination->initialize($config);

    $this->_DB_FORUM->select('some query');
    $query = $this->_DB_FORUM->get('table_name', $config['per_page'], $this->uri->segment(4));
```

I am returning result of query.

```
return $query->result_array();
```

Now, when I click on page numbers page gets reloaded and so all reset. I know there must be issue with `$config['base_url'] = site_url().'/home';`, so what should be here that i will be on same view, only sub-view should get reload and pagination should work.
I am not getting as I am beginner with CI. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Umm... this seems like a javascript issue and not a codeigniter one?

Comment: ohhh.. can you explain, please